# os.path.isdir() and os.path.isfile() both returning False in script but return True (like they should) in the Python console

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to use `for` and the `os` module to run through a list of filenames, change the `itemtype` variable to either "FILE" or "DIRECTORY"  accordingly, and print that out. When I try to do this in a Python console, this works fine. However, when the almost identical piece of code runs in my script, both the `isdir()` and `isfile()` functions return false.

I try this in the console:

```py
>>> import os
>>> files = os.listdir()
>>> print(files)
['namebydate.py', 'order.bat', 'storebydate.py', 'test', '__pycache__']
>>> for i in files:
...  itemtype=''
...  if os.path.isdir(i):
...   itemtype='DIRECTORY'
...  elif os.path.isfile(i):
...   itemtype='FILE'
...
...  print('{itemtype}'.format(itemtype=itemtype))
...
FILE
FILE
FILE
DIRECTORY
DIRECTORY
>>>
```

And it works perfectly fine.
But when my script runs and goes to its equivalent of that:

```py
for i in files:
    itemtype = ''
    if os.path.isdir(i):
        itemtype = 'DIRECTORY'
    elif os.path.isfile(i):
        itemtype = 'FILE'
    print('({current}/{total}) [{itemtype}] {name}'.format(
        current=str(files.index(i)+1),
        total=len(files),
        itemtype=itemtype,
        name=i))
```

The functions return false, leaving the `itemtype` value as an empty string, and the output becomes:

```
Listing...
(1/4) [] testdir
(2/4) [] testdoc1.txt
(3/4) [] testdoc2.txt
(4/4) [] testdoc3.txt
```

In this case, the expected result *should* be:

```
Listing...
(1/4) [DIRECTORY] testdir
(2/4) [FILE] testdoc1.txt
(3/4) [FILE] testdoc2.txt
(4/4) [FILE] testdoc3.txt
```

Comment: I ran your code, works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdir` and `isfile` requires `path` while `listdir` returns `name`. In other words, to check with `isdir` or `isfile`, you should append the path before filename. E.g:

```py
import os

dir = '/'
files = os.listdir(dir)
os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, files[0])
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, files[0])
```

Comment: Ah, that worked! Still not sure why it worked in the console but not the script without that, but adding it into the script seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure but did you run console in root directory?

Comment: It was running in the same directory the script used.

Comment: Weird. Because if I run `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir` to check item in root directory, it works. Because the path equals to name in this case specifically